# Not able to set form data into database using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project_site model where user uploads name file into database. and another model is project_manager which accepts and rejects Boolean field and remark field along with each project_site entries. but I am unable to set remark and status boolean data into project_manager database. Here is my code:

project_manager.rb

```
class ProjectManager < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project_site
end
```

project_site.rb

```
class ProjectSite < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_managers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name,:attendance, presence: true
end
```

project_manager_dashboard

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Uploaded By</th>
        <th>Attendance File</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @project_sites.each do |project_site| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= project_site.name.titleize %></td>
            <% if project_site.attendance? %>
              <td><%= link_to "View Attendance", project_site.attendance.url, :class => "fi-page-export-csv" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <td>No File Present</td>
            <% end %>

            <td>
              <%= form_for [ @project_site, @project_manager ] do |f| %>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="medium-6 columns">
                    <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
                    <%= f.label :approve %>
                    <%= f.radio_button :status, false  %>
                    <%= f.label :reject %>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="medium-6 cloumns">
                    <%= f.label :remark %><br/>
                    <%= f.text_area :remark %>
                  </div>

                    </div>
                  <div>
                    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary' %>
                  </div>

              <% end %>
            </td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Action', project_site, :class=>'button tiny primary' %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

project_manager_controller.rb

```
class ProjectManagersController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
   @project_manager = ProjectManager.new
   #@project_manager.project_site_id = @project_site.id
  end


  def create
     @project_manager = ProjectManager.new(remark_params)
    @project_manager.project_site_id = params[:project_site_id]
    @project_manager.save

    redirect_to project_managers_path
  end

  def remark_params
    params.require(:project_manager).permit(:remark, :status)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :project_sites
  resources :project_managers
```

Comment: You need a nested routes `resources :project_sites do 
  resources :project_managers end`

Comment: hi changing routes still does not resolved problem. on changing routes like this raises error on form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller Side

```
   class ProjectManagersController < ApplicationController

      def index
       @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
       @project_manager = ProjectManager.new
      end


      def create
        @project_manager = ProjectManager.new(remark_params)
        @project_manager.save

        redirect_to project_managers_path
      end

      def remark_params
        params.require(:project_manager).permit(:remark, :status, :project_site_id)
      end
    end
```

View Side

```
<tbody>
  <% @project_sites.each do |project_site| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= project_site.name.titleize %></td>
        <% if project_site.attendance? %>
          <td><%= link_to "View Attendance", project_site.attendance.url, :class => "fi-page-export-csv" %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td>No File Present</td>
        <% end %>

        <td>
          <%= form_for @project_manager do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="medium-6 columns">
                <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
                <%= f.label :approve %>
                <%= f.radio_button :status, false  %>
                <%= f.label :reject %>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="medium-6 cloumns">
                <%= f.label :remark %><br/>
                <%= f.text_area :remark %>
              </div>
                <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: project_site.id%>
                </div>
              <div>
                <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary' %>
              </div>

          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Action', project_site, :class=>'button tiny primary' %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: i am now getting this error- "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass):
    42:               <%= form_for @project_manager do |f| %>
    43:                 <div class="row">
    44:                     <div class="medium-6 columns">
    45:                       <%= f.hidden_field :project_site_id, params[:project_site_id]%>
    46:                       <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
    47:                       <%= f.label :status, "approve", value: true %>
    48:

Comment: @mick HI, I can't get it with the given log, can you just replace `[ @project_site, @project_manager ]` to `@project_manager` in your existing code, so that can point to correct action on form submission.

Comment: @mick Let me know if you get it ? or if you need any further guidance. Thanks

Comment: hey when i do changes as you said i am able to render form correctly but i am still not able to set data in database.

Comment: @mick So can you now amend the radio button/label as I wrote in the answer?

Comment: same error- "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @mick, By the way, can you check it on the server console if it's rollback due to some reason?

Comment: hey i checked with updated answer problem is still same. when i un-comment the line "   #@project_manager.project_site_id = @project_site.id". i get this error - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: hi thanks it resolved the problem but i am now not able to access the strored boolean value by -               <% project_site.project_managers.each do |project_manager| %>
                <% if project_manager.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif project_manager.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>

Comment: @mick Glad to know that it's resolved, may I know what issue you are facing while accessing boolean data about status?

Comment: @mick Never do this `f.hidden_field :project_site_id`, its wrong, if not validating it from back-end!

Answer (score 0):

The form you created is correct, you need a nested form because you're creating project managers for project sites. However, if your form is nested, you also need nested routes. For creating a new record it should look like this:

```
routes.rb

resources :project_sites do
  resources :project_managers, only: [:create]
end
```

(It's called shallow nesting, you only nest when you create a new record). That way you don't have to pass the project site id in a hidden field, it will be part of the url.

Now this should route the http request, that gets submitted when you click 'submit' on the form to your ProjectManagersController. The code there looks fine.
If the record still does not get created, check the logs in your terminal where you run `rails server`. Can you see where the POST request is coming in? Go through all the lines and look if they make sense. 
I have a feeling, that the project site doesn't get assigned to the project manager and thats why the record cannot be saved. Because the `belongs_to :project_site` in the `project_manager.rb` contains a validation. Is there a rollback instead of a saving of the preoject manager?

Comment: I had a typo after `only`. I changed the solution - does it fix it? If not, please paste the error here